# What does it mean if your Windows laptop shows "Consider Changing Your Battery"?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery

I am currently getting a a message saying "consider changing laptop battery" when my battery gets to 10%.

I also have a red X over the battery Icon all the time. I think my battery is ok though.

How can I check? Or how can I remove the error?

Comment: What make and model laptop do you have?

Comment: [What should I do if I receive a "Consider replacing your battery" notification?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/consider-replacing-your-battery) — Microsoft has covered that already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I check how well a battery is doing

1. let it discharge completely.
2. Time how long it takes to charge to
   100%.
3. Remove AC adapter and time how long it takes to deplete if it's dead in less than 35-45 mins. You probably need to replace it. How old is it?

Comment: Just hit a year a week ago

Comment: I have seen them go out with heavy usage in that time frame. Especially ones with fewer cells.

Comment: I thinks it just a six cell. ITs going to cost $150 to replace it won't it? It's only a low end laptop, so I don't won't to spend much on it

Comment: They are sometimes pricey it shouldn't be that much. Just try and find one made by a 3rd party. It'll most likely be cheaper than one from the manufacturer. Do a google search for the battery model "bfg45-456 replacement battery"

Comment: avoid deep discharges (except when resetting fuel gauge or reconditioning a battery)

Comment: Thanks Kelbizzle. I have no idea what you are talking about Molly...

Comment: @Fastboy42: Deep discharges (discharging until [almost] empty) are bad for Lithium-Ion accumulators (which is what most laptops use). See e.g. http://www.batteryuniversity.com/parttwo-34.htm

Comment: If you actually intend to use the laptop while on battery, even 45 minutes may not be enough. How much work can you get done in 45 minutes?

Comment: Deep discharges aren't "Bad" They're just not needed as lithium ion's don't have memory. In fact they should be fully discharged once in a while for calibration purposes. I dunno the frequency but I do know that if a battery is incorrectly telling you the time left until it's dead. Deep cycling it will sometimes correct the issue.


45 minutes is probably a little less than half the normal capacity of a 6 cell battery. Normal capacity being around 3 hours or so give or take a half hour.

Answer (score 4):

Your laptop has software for monitoring the battery - showing the current charge, how much time it estimates you have before you need to recharge etc. This may also have access to historical data of charging times etc. or the expected charge times etc of your battery.

[The software has detected that your battery is not holding it's charge for as long as expected, or isn't fully charging.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/consider-replacing-your-battery)

You should therefore consider changing the battery. You should be able to find one on-line. Either search for your laptop make and model plus the word "battery" or take out the battery and search for the make/model of the battery itself.

As long as you go for a reputable supplier (Amazon perhaps) then there is less likelihood of getting a counterfeit battery, or if there is a problem, more chance of getting a replacement or your money back.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming this is an older system and the battery has gotten a considerable number of cycles, and a low capacity compared to the design capacity - MS has a writeup on this in their [help site](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/consider-replacing-your-battery)

If the battery actually works fine however, this may mean that something is off - [some systems apparently misreport their battery capacity](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2293330), and as such give the warning even when everything is working fine - a bios update may fix this.

There seems to be another [fix for it here](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/windows_battery_power_settings/en-us) , tho this seems to be just settings tweaks

Answer (score 1):

Whether you ultimately replace the battery or not, you should visit this website:

**[Battery University](http://www.batteryuniversity.com/index.htm)** - one of the most comprehensive resources for batteries (of all types)

Answer (score 1):

The maximum capacity of Lithium-Ion batteries decreases over time.  Several factors contribute to how fast they degrade (such as heat, moisture, and usage).

When Windows detects that the capacity has degraded by a certain amount, it will notify you that you should replace the battery.  This will ensure that your system maximizes its potential battery life.

If you keep this computer plugged in most of the time, then you have little to worry about with this  message.  However, if you like mobility and the ability to use your computer for extended periods without needing to charge, then you should consider buying a new battery for it.

***DO NOT*** buy a used battery, as it may also have degraded considerably and would be little better than your current one.  Also, buying new batteries straight from manufacturers can be very expensive (usually a battery straight from a manufacturer costs a minimum of about $120).  If you are looking in to buying a new battery, sites like [Ebay](http://www.ebay.com/), Amazon, and [NewEgg](http://www.newegg.com/) are good places to start.  Good luck!