# What does it mean when your Windows laptop shows you the message, "Consider Replacing Your Battery"?

Tags: windows, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Consider Changing Battery](https://superuser.com/questions/101029/consider-changing-battery)

Recently my Windows laptop has displayed the message:

> Consider Replacing Your Battery

- What does it mean?
- What should I do?
- What leads to these kinds of messages?
- What pre-cautions should I apply?